# Split file base on first row in separated files in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I need to split file base on first row. Example data:

```
101,row2,row3
103,row2,row3
102,row2,row3
101,row2,row3
```

So these will be split into 3 files (one file for 101 rows one for 102 and one for 103) . Output can be XML or flat file

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to create a custom pipeline for that function. You can reference this post which references a couple blog posts in the answer, it will tell you how to implement it, but your implementation will differ some.

[Custom pipeline BizTalk 2010 to split FLAT files](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkgeneral/thread/45a8f58c-be22-4711-be1c-1923448c9bf3)